# Disable "Call via hangouts" in Contacts.google.com in browser - use tel: instead

Tags: gmail, chrome-for-android, google-apps, google-contacts

I use "click to call" from my phone often on phone numbers in my laptop browser (Chrome) and recently tried it from Gmail and Contacts tabs of Google apps. I even created a page to paste numbers in to use this function: https://craiglambie.com/ClickToCallForm.html

However this sends a *link* to call using Hangouts - when I want to use the mobile/cell phone to call usually.

Is there a way to disable the *hangouts* link, and make it a "normal" tel: link that the phone accepts?

Comment: Hi, I assume you want to fix the link from the laptop (Google Contacts web app), not on the phone? If so, [webapps.se] should be more suitable since it's more about manipulating the web page (e.g. using userscript), not Android. Let me know if you want this to be migrated to there.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - you are probably right. tbh I didn't notice I was in a "specialist" android community until after I posted, just thought it was vanilla SE.

Comment: Could you please move this to "web applications"? @AndrewT. Thanks

Comment: Done, I'll clean up my comments on there, you might want to too.

Comment: "click to call" is not a generally available built-in Google Contacts feature. Are you using a Chrome extension? Do you have a Google Voice phone number? How doe the link to call using Hangouts link look? Have you already tried to change the app used by Android to open links?